# unable to update/upgrade 1 package

Tags: apt, upgrade, pop-os, dist-upgrade

I am unable to update my pop-os distribution due to the inability to upgrade 1 package.

```
apt list --upgradable -a
```

returns

```
Listing... Done
pop-system-updater/impish 0.1.0~1657035226~21.10~6f0d903 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.1.0~1655219862~21.10~b81523a]
pop-system-updater/now 0.1.0~1655219862~21.10~b81523a amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 0.1.0~1657035226~21.10~6f0d903]
```

I tried the below functions without success

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get full-upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

anyone has a clue about what is broken and how I could fix it?

Comment: It looks there was a cut/paste issue: everything is displayed except the package name (right before `/now`). Or is the name actually not displayed?

Comment: edited with proper output of "apt list" command

Comment: Have you run `apt update`? Do you realise you're mixing `apt` and `apt-get`? What responses do you get to the `apt-get ...upgrade*` commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after following [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/ult2sa/upgrading_popos_2110_to_2204_fails_with_unmet/) (forcing the replacement of the sources) I manage to update and upgrade with several reboots, and apt autoremove.